# Client for django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django rest framework is a great tool to expose data in restful protocol, but does it have a built in client that does the heavy lifting at the back to enable easy implementation in SOA architecture between different django projects?

So far I haven't found much from the django rest framework [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), hopefully someone can shed some light on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "official" client for DRF, since REST-APIs mostly don't have much "heavy-lifting" as you perhaps know it from SOAP or similar techniques.

For most REST-APIs [slumber](http://slumber.readthedocs.org/en/v0.6.0/) is the easiest way to connect to these. It handles url-building, authentication and json-dump/load.

Comment: As of this writing, slumber does not have very good support for resources with dashes in their names or for querying the root resource.  Hopefully, this saves someone the headache I just went through.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a package that mimics the django queryset over DRF.

[django-rest-framework-queryset](https://github.com/variable/django-rest-framework-queryset)